# chunking/text parsing using NLTK

Tags: nlp, text-parsing, nltk

I am trying to parse some text and diagram it, like you would a sentence. I am new to NLTK and am trying to find something in NLTK that will help me accomplish this. So far, I have seen `nltk.ne_chunk` and `nltk.pos_tag`. I find them to be not very helpful and I am not able to find any good online documentation.

I have also tried to use the `LancasterStemmer`, but I don't fully understand what it does or how it should be used or why it even exists.

Can somebody please help me out with this? I'm really at a loss and getting quite frustrated without any guiding lights.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, exactly?  Do you actually need semantic parsing, or simply lexical analysis?  What is the digram you're trying to produce?

Comment: Ultimately, I want to be able to create a "tree" which represents the data in the text. Once I have this done, then I can do the same for another piece of text (on the same subject - say a lecture) and compare where the two are similar/different and incorporate the differences. This can ultimately yield a "tree" that has the most accurate representation of that lecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is actually a really hard task, as in the end, whether your program has succeeded or failed is an entirely subjective measure. When this is the case, it usually means constructing a program to solve the problem is hard. There are people who get paid to work on these kind problems in universities.

If you wanted to have a stab at it, I'd suggest trying for to use some kind on automated lexical analysis tool rather than trying to manually parse and annotate, and then leverage your parse tree. Usually parse-trees represent syntactic analyses, ie the structure of the sentence. You on the other hand are concerned rather with semantic analysis, ie what it means - or at least whether two sentences are similar or different (which is actually a bit easier than what something means).

You could look into some off-the-shelf automatic summarization tools. These try to score sentences by how important they are to a piece of text and filter out sentences which are less important than a specified threshold. Not that this really helps you that much as you still have the problem of needing the merge the summaries.

Comment: Thank you. Right now, I am trying to get the syntactic structure of a sentence so that I can do the semantic parsing later on. Please tell me if I'm going in the wrong direction because I AM still a student and am not an expert and would appreciate such feedback.
In either case, would you recommend any particular nltk tool/module to help with this?

Comment: If I were to have a go at this task, I'm not sure that I would bother with parsing. I think you're better off using a statistical approach which usually uses a bag of words approach (or similar). This is what it sounds like, just treating each sentence as a pile of words and not worrying about the positioning of the words. Some technologies that may help you are clustering based approaches and possibly TF-IDF. Perhaps read up on these and see if you think they might help you. NLTK has modules for both of these.

Comment: Thank you humble coffee. Is it possible though, that you could point me to any specific nltk module? Perhaps something that you have used and think might be appropriate for my problem?